# Excel 2013 auto generated macro VBA code does not work when attempting to run the macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a very simple Excel macro in Office 2013.  The macro should create a line chart with titles on the x and y axes.  I go to the "Developer" tab and select "Record Macro".  I create my chart and everything looks fine.  When I view my auto-generated VBA code it looks like the following:

```
Sub SimplePlotExample()
    Range("A1:B11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$11")
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    Selection.Caption = "This is my rows title"
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    Selection.Caption = "This is my y axis title"
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I try to run this macro, the y-axis title does not get created and instead the x-axis has the title intended for the y-axis.  If I go into the VBA code directly, comment out the line "Selection.Caption = "This is my y axis title"" and manually replace it with the code as shown below everything works fine.

```
Sub SimplePlotExample()
    Range("A1:B11").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$11")
        ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
        Selection.Caption = "This is my rows title"
        ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    '   Add the 2 lines of code below manually to my macro code
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "This is my hand-edited y axis title"
    '    Selection.Caption = "This is my y axis title"   ### This is the auto-generated line commented out
        Range("A1").Select
    End Sub
```

My questions is.....Why does the "auto-generated" VBA code not work correctly?  I have found other threads that perhaps indicate this may have been an issue with past versions of Excel, am I to assume that this is also an issue with Excel 2013?  I am using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013.

Thanks!

Comment: The value of Stack Overflow is that people google up their specific problem, and end up on questions asked by people that had the same issue they're facing, and find valuable answers easily. Please [edit] your title to something searchable.

Comment: ^^ Yes, I saw the question and thought "hmm, someone is having an issue with creating an Excel macro in VBA - that's strange - I wonder what would be preventing them from doing that", and then read the question and saw that it was completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on a new sheet.

```
Sub SimplePlotExample()
    Range("A1:B11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(332, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$11")
    With ActiveChart
     'chart name
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Chart Name"
     'X axis name
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "This is my X-Axis"
     'y-axis name
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "This is my Y axis title"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It fixes the problem.  What more elaboration do you need?  The difference between my code and the OP code is the reason it wasn't working.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I should elaborate.  My goal is to create a utility that can be used by non-SW engineers.  The utility will allow these engineers to create their own macros and run them using the base code.  Since they are not versed in VBA I am hoping that we can use the "auto-generated" Excel macro VBA code to create macros.  The problem is that, apparently, the auto-generated code does not always work correctly and I am not sure why.  Perhaps it is a setting I do not have correct?  Some other easy-to-fix issue?  Thanks.

Comment: What macros will the engineers create?  Are they trying to create a chart for specific data in a specific range?  Are you wanting the engineers to autogenerate their own code with the recording function?  My code could be changed to  operate on a selected area instead of a fixed range.  The engineer would only need to select their data and run the macro, which can be changed to use the current selection as it's data source.  Would that solve your problem?  Sometimes when you hit a wall you can climb over it or go around it.  Why question its existence?

Comment: The utility I'm trying to create needs to be very flexible, meaning that the data plotted, the format of the data/plots, labeling, etc. could all change on a daily basis if we are debugging an issue.  So my utility will start with a macro that does what we need it to do 90% of the time but I want the option for the engineers to replace the default macro with one of their own.  And they are not VBA programmers, so I was hoping that I could have them create their own macro using the Excel "auto-generation" feature and use that code to replace the default macro.